# How to transfer lucene36 to lucene 40

Tags: java, lucene

Here is my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "time.stop";
    try {
        StopWordList swl = new StopWordList(name);
        System.out.println(swl.getWords().toString());
        Analyzer az = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40, swl.getWords());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    }
}
```

Here is the error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor StandardAnalyzer(Version, Set) is undefined

```
at StopWordList.main(StopWordList.java:49)
```

Comment: what does `swl.getWords()` return ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code which initializes `Analyzer` should look like this:

```
Analyzer az = new StandardAnalyzer(
  Version.LUCENE_40, 
  new CharArraySet(
    Version.LUCENE_40, 
    swl.getWords(), 
    true
  )
);
```